# Can I change “Is there” to negative?

Tags: negation

I have not seen the case of using the following expressions.

- Is/Are there no problem?
- Is/Aren't there (any) problems?

Is it possible to make "Is there" a negative question? There are too few Google search results that I got. Are these really used?

Comment: _**Isn't** there any problem?_

Comment: If you are asking in this particular frame, then I am not sure. But in general, *isn't there* is more used than *aren't there*.

Comment: You can use the negative when you were expecting something to be true. "Isn't there any food?" Or rhetorically, "Isn't X the boss?"

Comment: Aren't there any people in the room? Aren't there is for plural nouns. Always. Isn't there a person in the room? Do you mean negative or negative interrogative. Not the same thing at all.